# Why is there a huge difference in performance between the C++ Debug version and the Release version, but not C#?

Tags: c#, c++, performance

In some large-scale C++ projects, the Debug version is almost useless, such as some game engines UnrealEngine, Ogre3d, etc. Because the Debug version of the program is too stuck to run, it is almost unusable. But when I was developing a C# program, I was surprised to find that the difference in experience between the Debug version and the Release version of the C# application was not so great that it was impossible to distinguish between debug and release. why?

```
// test C# code
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp21
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void DoSomething()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0;i<10000000; ++i)
            {
                builder.Append(i.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"{builder.ToString().Length}");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine("DEBUG:");
#else
            Console.WriteLine("Release:");
#endif

            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            DoSomething();

            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

DEBUG:
68888890
00:00:00.9831842

Release:
68888890
00:00:00.8958183

```
// test cpp code
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/progress.hpp>

void DoSomething()
{
    std::string str;
    char buf[64];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        sprintf_s(buf, "%d", i);
        str.append(buf);
    }

    std::cout << str.size() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
#ifdef _DEBUG
    printf_s("DEBUG:");
#else
    printf_s("RELEASE:");
#endif

    boost::progress_timer timer;
    
    DoSomething();
}
```

DEBUG:5888890
0.33 s

RELEASE:5888890
0.06 s

Comment: Because the rules of C++ allow for greater optimization? I'm not so great on C# but I imagine strong typing and the C++ concept of undefined behaviour have a lot to do with it

Comment: The code in your C++ loop could be replaced with `str += std::to_string(i);`.

Comment: As for the differences between the debug and release builds of the C# code, perhaps the C# compiler does more optimizations on debug builds than a typical C++ compiler does? Or that the C# code is pretty optimal and can't be that much more optimized by the compiler for release builds? And perhaps the C# compiler relies on JIT compilation by the run-time, which means you need to run more times to really see a difference?

Comment: Try `builder.Append(i);` and the C# might go a bit faster. Also pre-initialize the `StringBuilder` to a large enough size to fit the data.

Comment: There are multiple reasons, but the Big One in C++ is the need to detect undefined behavior in the Debug configuration.  The /RTC compile option is very valuable but extremely expensive, adding gobs of overhead to each function call.  In the posted snippet, the probable cause is sprintf_s(), the Debug build uses the debug flavor of the runtime which can detect that the program passed the wrong value for the buffer size.

Comment: Your C# code reports the size of 68,888,890, while C++ - 5,888,890. By closely examining your code, one can see that the loop count in C# is 10M, and in C++ - 1M.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that c++ can optimize more. Since all work is done ahead of time it can spend however much time it wants on figuring out the optimal way to convert the code. .Net compiled by the just-in-time compiler (jitter), and therefore need to compile code *fast*, so it does not have time for any costly optimization. Newer .Net releases support tiered compiling, so could allow more optimization for frequently used code.

There might also be restrictions in what optimization can be applied since c# and .Net is more focused on ensuring correctness and developer productivity than the performance focused mentality of c++.

Note that attaching a debugger to .Net code will disable some types of optimizations, so you need to be careful when doing any comparisons. You also need to be careful with c++ code, since some higher level of optimizations can cause the compiler to just remove entire sections of code if there is some undefined behavior. Also check that the c++ code uses high precision timers, and not the computer clock. I would not be surprised if something named "progress" would use the later.